# Remove items from one array of objects from another array of objects with _.differenceBy

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two arrays of objects:

```
var defendantList = [
  {
    label: "Joe BLow"
    value: "Joe Blow"
  },
  {
    label: "Sam Snead"
    value: "Sam Snead"
  },
  {
    label: "John Smith"
    value: "John Smith"
  },
];

var dismissedDefendants = [
  {
    date: 'someDateString',
    value: "Joe Blow"
  },
  {
    date: "someOtherDateString",
    value: "Sam Snead"
  }
];
```

I need to create an array that has values from defendantList that are not contained in dismissedDefendants. How can I do that simply, either with lodash or a standard JS array function? I'm looking at lodash's [_.differenceBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#differenceBy), since it has an iteratee, but I can't quite figure out how.

**UPDATE**: the desired end result in this example is just an array with the non-matching object:

```
  var newArray = [
      {
        label: "John Smith"
        value: "John Smith"
      },
    ];
```

Thanks.

Comment: @HenryDev No, since I know in this case label and value are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `_.differenceBy()`:

```
_.differenceBy(defendantList, dismissedDefendants, 'value');
```

```js
var defendantList = [
  {
    label: "Joe BLow",
    value: "Joe Blow"
  },
  {
    label: "Sam Snead",
    value: "Sam Snead"
  },
  {
    label: "John Smith",
    value: "John Smith"
  },
];

var dismissedDefendants = [
  {
    date: 'someDateString',
    value: "Joe Blow"
  },
  {
    date: "someOtherDateString",
    value: "Sam Snead"
  }
];

var result = _.differenceBy(defendantList, dismissedDefendants, 'value');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And an ES6 solution based on [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```
defendantList.filter(function({ value }) { 
  return !this.has(value); // keep if value is not in the Set
}, new Set(dismissedDefendants.map(({ value }) => value))); //create a Set of unique values in dismissedDefendants and assign it to this
```

```js
var defendantList = [
  {
    label: "Joe BLow",
    value: "Joe Blow"
  },
  {
    label: "Sam Snead",
    value: "Sam Snead"
  },
  {
    label: "John Smith",
    value: "John Smith"
  },
];

var dismissedDefendants = [
  {
    date: 'someDateString',
    value: "Joe Blow"
  },
  {
    date: "someOtherDateString",
    value: "Sam Snead"
  }
];

var result = defendantList.filter(function({ value }) { 
  return !this.has(value); 
}, new Set(dismissedDefendants.map(({ value }) => value)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using plain Javascript. Hope it helps!

```js
var defendantList = [
  {
    label: "Joe BLow",
    value: "Joe Blow"
  },
  {
    label: "Sam Snead",
    value: "Sam Snead"
  },
  {
    label: "John Smith",
    value: "John Smith"
  },
];

var dismissedDefendants = [
  {
    date: 'someDateString',
    value: "Joe Blow"
  },
  {
    date: "someOtherDateString",
    value: "Sam Snead"
  }
];

for(var i in defendantList){
    for(var j in dismissedDefendants){
      if(defendantList[i].value === dismissedDefendants[j].value){
        var index = defendantList.indexOf(defendantList[i]);
        if (index > -1) {
        defendantList.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    }
}
console.log(defendantList);
```